# NHibernate Proxy Validator changes in 2.1

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, castle-dynamicproxy

Can someone please help me understand the following:

In the previous version of NHibernate (2.0.1) the following property will
validate and is compatible with the Castle Proxies:

```
internal virtual BusinessObject Parent
{
  get { /*code*/ }
}
```

However, in 2.1 it errors saying that the types should be
'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'.
I have issues with this because marking a property with 'protected
internal' exposes the property to inherited types in OTHER assemblies
(effectively protected OR internal). Given that this was never a
requirement before, it feels like a bit of a bad requirement to impose
now.

Can someone please explain why this requirement is now there and what
it is trying to enforce so I can at least understand what it is
intending to achieve.

If this restriction is not entirely needed, and I am 100% certain
these types of properties will NEVER map to DB properties I am
intending to create my own Mashup ByteCode provider using the Castle
proxy factory and the Type Validator from 2.0.1. However, I'm definitely open to any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's the change](http://fisheye3.atlassian.com/changelog/nhibernate?cs=3842) and [here's the reason](http://nhjira.koah.net/browse/NH-1515) for that change. According to the report, it was breaking proxy behavior.

Comment: Nice one. I guess the forced exposure of members in this case is a downside to using proxies in general. Thanks.